# Can you provide clarification on the Arka Saptami reference in the Brahma Purana?

Tags: rituals, brahma-purana

27.26-32 states "On the first day of the following holy rite the devotee shall drink a palmful of water held in a leaf cup of the Arka plant."
Is the reference to a holy rite that of the Arka Saptami rite or something else?

Does this mean begin taking water on the 7th day of the bright lunar fortnight, or the day after?  Does one half of the cycle mean 'add water for 24 days + the 7th day of the lunar fortnight for a total of 25 days', or is the process continued for 23 days after the fortnight, thus creating a 48-day cycle?

Does the taking of water begin on Masik Krishna Janmashtami, or the day after this year?
Is the largest volume of water 24 or 25 palmfuls?
Is it all taken in at once during Puja, or is there a timing which is allowed to take in the water?
Where can I find details on how to carry out this rite?

Comment: Are you aware of the following details? "On the first day of the following holy rite the devotee shall drink a palmful of water held in a leaf cup of the Arka plant. He shall increase it by one every day for twenty-four days. Then he shall decrease the number by one every day. This process continues for two years and the holy rite is concluded then. This holy rite Arkasaptamī bestows all cherished desires. It is a praiseworthy holy rite." From https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216097.html — If so, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question, Gabe. I appreciate your reference as I am familiar with the passage which is cited therein.  I have many questions though which remain unresolved for me. the rite itself is that which I seek to understand. Why does it exist? Are there steps to an associated ritual or a prayer to accompany the intake of water? When during the day should one fulfill this obligation and promise? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the list of vratas found in the [History Of Ddarmasastra](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.505779/page/n267/mode/2up), the Arkasaptamī reference can be found in the Padma Purāṇa  V.75.86-106:

> Arkasaptamī—tithi; for two years; deity Sun; one is to drink from a cup made of the leaves of arka plant; HV I.788-789 (from Brah.). Vide Pad. V.75.86-106 which state that vrata to be begun in Uttarāyaṇa on a Sunday in śukla pakṣa; on 5th ekabhakta, on 6th nakta, on 7th fast and on 8th pāraṇā.

I believe this corresponds to the Arkāṅgasaptamī found in [Chapter I.77](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364200.html) of the following edition of the Padma Purana, which is event titled Arkāṅgasaptamī ("The Vow of Saptamī in Houour of the Sun"). So the whole chapter is devoted towards explaining the vow.

> 85. A wise man, having duly practised the vow of **Arkāṅgasaptamī (falling on a Sunday)**, becomes purified from sin, and having obtained the desired things in this world, would obtain salvation.
> 86. I shall tell (you) the distinctive mark (of this vow) and also the right (to be performed) in every month. Due to the propitiousness of this vow he is honoured by gods in heaven.
> 87. **When the Uttarāyaṇa sets in, on a Sunday** and on the male asterism in the bright half, one should receive the vow of Saptamī.
> 88. The wise say that Hasta, Maitra (i.e. Anurādhā), Puṣya, Śravas (i.e. Sravaṇa), Mṛga and Punarvasu are male asterisms.
> 89. It is said that one should eat only once on the fifth day, should eat only at night on the sixth day, should fast on the seventh day, and the fast would be broken on the eighth day.
> 90. He eats the tip of the Arka-tree, pure cowdung, good black pepper, water, fruit and root. At night he should eat, or should eat once a day according to the rules; or (should drink) milk or eat food anointed with ghee. These are told in order (to be the things which he should partake of). Doing (i.e. taking) them in this order and thus observing the vow of the Sun on the seventh day, he obtains the desired fruit.
> 91. Without touching them with his teeth, he should drink, with water, the tip of the Arka tree, a particular pair of small leaves from the branch of the Arka tree on the north-east of the village. He should also drink with water in a small quantity, without touching with his teeth, pure cowdung not fallen on the ground, holding it with the middle finger and the thumb. He should also drink with water and without touching it with his teeth, an unbruised, old, big, dry, good black pepper. He should also drink water sacred to Viṣṇu, flowing from the roots of his fingers. Without touching it with his teeth, he should drink with water one of the fruits from among dates and coconuts. The food should be anointed with ghee and should be of the measure of a peacock’s egg. The quantity of the ghee should be like that only.

However there seems to be no reference to the amount of years. And I cannot locate "HV I.788-789". Perhaps someone else can assist with this.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge, Guru Gabe.  This will help guide my actions.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope this helps. I will add to answer if I find other reference.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I hope you are well. I am not familiar ith thi

Answer (score 0):

According to Chapter Twenty-seven, v 26-32, of the Brahma Purana Part I, "This process continues for two years and the holy rite is concluded then."